# Can “mettere in canna” mean ‘to put in jail’?

Tags: meaning, idioms

While looking for the origin of the Spanish and Portuguese word *cana*, which in several South-American countries means ‘jail’, ‘police’, and ‘police officer’, I came across the suggestion that it may come from the Italian *mettere in cana* (*mettere in canna* perhaps?) which would mean ‘to arrest, to put in jail’ [(Spanish Wikipedia)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cana_(lunfardo)).

I looked up *canna* (it looks as though *cana* is not even an Italian word) in various Italian online dictionaries, including the rather detailed [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/canna/), and could not find *mettere in canna* or any sense of *canna* related to jail or the police.

So is or was *mettere in canna* ever used to mean ‘to arrest’? Which sense of *canna* would this come from?

Comment: Never, ever heard anything even similar to that. Just to hazard a very wild guess, might there be some (perhaps misunderstood) link with *cane* (“dog”, also used figuratively in several senses) or *canaglia* (“scoundrel”, also etymologically related to *cane*)? Or, with the idiom *essere povero in canna* (to be destitute)? Just some brainstorming...

Comment: @DaG Thanks for that. There are tons of suggestions for the origin of that *cana*; the most plausible to me is *incaenare* which is (I hope it is) *incatenare* in a Venetian dialect (along with *cana*, there is also *encanar*, 'to arrest').

Comment: Ernesto Ferrero which, according to Spanish Wikipedia, claims such Italian origin of this word, is the Italian writer Ernesto Ferrero?

Comment: @Charo *Mettere in canna* was suggested by Américo Castro. Ernesto Ferrero (don't know whether he is *the* Ernesto Ferrero) says it is because the police in Verona are called *canna* on account of the pale colour of their uniforms.

Comment: Is this question somehow related to the one about the origin of  "can" meaning "jail"?

Comment: @Gio lol, indeed. All part of the same quest, which started [here (in Portuguese)](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/qual-a-origem-da-express%C3%A3o-vai-em-cana). It was suggested [here](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?cana) that the lunfardo *cana* comes from the English *can*. That's rather doubtful though as *encanado* meaning 'arrested' appears in print 33 years before *can* as 'jail'.

Comment: Just to double-check, which is the suggested first appearance of “can” as “jail”?

Comment: @DaG Oxford English Dictionary says 1912. Check it out [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/356053/origin-of-can-in-the-sense-of-jail).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  expression "mettere in canna" has nothing to do with jail but it descends from  the habit/operation of putting the bayonet barrel, that is the knife attached to rifles used in the past especially by the Napoleonic army and during World War I. 
Figuratively it means to prepare yourself to do something very challenging and difficult.

Comment: Do you also say *mettere in canna* for bayonets? The formal expression is *inastare (la baionetta)*.

Comment: Well,  to put tha bullet into a weapon should be "mettere il colpo in canna" whereas "mettere in canna" is like innestare la baionetta, an action which was usually performed when the  soldier was out of bullets and was about to fight hand-to-hand

Answer (score 3):

I never heard of an usage of  "mettere in canna" as "to arrest".
On my experience,  "canna" here is meant as the barrel of a fire weapon (e.g. a shotgun). So "mettere in canna" means something like "I have loaded the weapon and I am ready to fire" a figurative expression that could mean "everything is ready (to do something)"

Comment: Do you mean *mettere in canna* in the same sense in which we might say *colpo in canna*? I am not sure this usage is what's referred in the OP.

Comment: I've never heard of a different usage...

Comment: Expressions that means "put in prison" that I am aware of are "_mettere al gabbio_" or "_mettere in gattabuia_"

Comment: @DenisNardin I don't know what I referred in the question is any actual usage at all. I found the claim *mettere in cana* meant 'to arrest'; couldn't find anything in the dictionaries to support that claim. So I asked. There are usages that do not come in dictionaries, Italy being such a diverse country and all, so maybe someone would know something that's not in the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I would say YES, in some dialects. As in English, "the can" can mean jail, so putting someone in the "can" could mean putting them in jail. Also, as in English, "can" can mean ass, so "mettere denare in canna" of a donkey means to put money in the ass of a donkey (and call him "sir").

Comment: Which dialects? And are you sure that some Italian dialects use “can”, exactly as in English? And where in the English-speaking world do “can” mean “ass”? And what does “to put money in the ass of a donkey” mean (I assume you don't mean it literally)?